# How do I collect user input for a 2D c-string array in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, char, c-strings

I'm working on a homework problem that wants me to collect user input to populate a 2D c-string array of a max of 20 sentences with 81 characters maximum each. While I understand how to initialize the array, I can't seem to stop collecting inputs from the user early, and am forced to continually hit enter to terminate the program.

```
int main()
{
    char sentences[20][81];

    cout << "Enter up to 20 sentences - when done, Press ENTER: ";
    input(sentences);



    cout << "\nPress any key to continue...";
    _getch();
    return 0;
}

void input(char str[20][81]) //This is our function to collect user sentence input
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        cin.getline(str[i], 81, '\0');
        if (str[i] == "\0")
            break;
    }
}
```

I expected cin.getline to get collect each string (maximum of 81 characters including null) from the user, and then upon seeing enter pressed collect the next string only stopping when 20 strings are entered or when enter is hit twice in a row (making whatever is str[i] == '\0').

Comment: enter does new line character what is \n not \0

Comment: The default value for third argument of `std::getline()` is `\n`. I wouldn't change it if I were in your place. This in mind, the following check would be `if (str[i][0] == '\0')`. The comparison, you did in `if (str[i] == "\0")` compares two pointers that is not what you intend. (There is a proper `==` if at least one of the arguments is `std::string` due to a resp. overload of `==`. But, for `char[]` or `char*`, `strcmp()` has to be used instead - or just the comparison of individual characters.)

Comment: Trying to use '\n' in lieu of '\0' didn't work, when I move to collect inputs I have to hit enter many times before the input function returns to main...